# Backbone.js - Moving data from one view to another

Tags: backbone.js

How to send data from one view to another which are on different urls?

Comment: This is generally done in the router. Could you provide a code snippet so we can better assist you?

Answer (score 2):

A little bit strange question, but OK, let's try to imagine your problem in complex and give an answer.

1. Imagine application for reading books (like iBooks in web). We have one parent View called ApplicationView which creates several children views and some of them are BookshelfView (available on #bookshelf url) and BookView (available on #book/:id url).

   Now, you mark your book as unread from your BookView and you know that your BookshelfView should change the appearance of this book. OK, it is not "moving data from one view to another". You just change the state of your model and your views catch this "change" event and update their html.
2. Let's describe more complicated situation. Imagine the same application. But at this time you decide to switch portrait orientation to landscape orientation. You make it in one view and you want this change to affect other application views. This can be done in several ways:

   - Views should stay [loosely coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) you should use some kind of [mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).
   - From  Backbone 0.9.9 you can use global Backbone object as Mediator, as Backbone supports Events interface
   - You can create and additional model for Mediation between two or more views but there is more beautiful solution:
   - If you have one parent view for several child views you already have that mediator. Just send events to parent view from one view and listen to that events on parent from other view.

I also recommend you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367037/how-should-2-seemingly-independent-views-under-the-same-parent-interact)