# How should 2 seemingly independent views under the same parent interact

Tags: backbone.js

Please consider following scenario:

```
<ParentView>
     <FilterSubview></FilterSubview>
     <ListSubview></ListSubview>
</ParentView>
```

To give you and example: I have a view which in turn shows view with filter (user can select to display books, magazines or both of them) and the list with items.
Both filter and list have corresponding models. Filter - what can we filter. List - list of all items.

Use case: user sees the full list and then can filter results by selecting only desired category.

Questions:

- How those two views should interact? Should they know about each other or should parent view handle it?
- Who should store filtered list to display? It could be list subview model directly or parent view can filter complete list and then pass it to render.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no one correct answer to your questions, but I'll try to explain a common, idiomatic way here.

Two sibling views should not know of each other. Instead they should interact via events through some kind of a mediator. Since in your case both `FilterView` and `ListSubView` share a common parent view which is responsible for rendering both of them, you could let the parent view mediate the events:

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
      this.listenTo(this.filterView, "filter", this.filterChanged);
  },
  filterChanged: function(filterValue) {
      this.listSubView.filter(filterValue);
  }
});

var FilterView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
      "change .filter" : "filterValueChanged"
  },
  filterValueChanged: function() {
      var filterValue = //get filter value...
      this.trigger("filter", filterValue);
  }
});
```

Alternatively (preferrably, even) you can cut out a middle man and use the [Mediator](http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/#mediatorpattern) pattern. For that you need a third component whose job it is to pass messages between parties who should not know of each other. If you're using Backbone 0.9.9, there's just such a mediator built in: the `Backbone` root object works as a global event bus for this purpose.

So:

```
//ListSubView
this.listenTo(Backbone, "listfilterchanged", this.filterChanged);

//FilterView
Backbone.trigger("listfilterchanged", filterValue);
```

Then there's the question of who should be responsible of the list data. I tend to prefer to have the most specialized component be in charge, but so that only **one** component is in charge. In your case that would mean that the `ListSubView` should manage the filtered list, but only if the `ParentView` doesn't need to operate on it. That's just a generalization though, so take it with a grain of salt and do what feels right for your case.

Comment: Thank you, also didn't know that Backbone itself could serve as mediator. Though I believe it would be better to connect views using common parent instead of moving all the way up to Backbone itself.